# Is it possible to get the actual calculated score of a custom ranked feed?

Tags: getstream-io

Right now getstream passes down ordinal score but not the actual internal score which makes it difficult to debug. I tried reading the api docs and inspecting the response but don't see anything. I'm also not quite sure how their own internal explorer works. When pressing "preview" the results set is limited and makes fine tuning difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our API call only returns an integer that orders the items. If you want the actual score, go to your organization's dashboard, click on your app, and click on the name of your ranking under the `Ranking Methods` header. then click on the "Preview Changes" you will see the ranked feed with the full score based on the ranking algorithm. There's also a search bar there if you want to change the feed and user_id values. I don't know if putting the actual score in the feed is on our roadmap but I can bring it up with the team.

Comment: Cool, will play with it a little more. We've started playing around with our ranking and it's a little tough to debug right now without seeing raw calculated scores against our actual data. I also noticed that the preview results aren't including custom properties which make understanding the *why* a little difficult without manually looking up and plugging in the numbers myself.